# NLTK Lemmatizing with list comprehension

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

How can I verify whether I am correctly using the NLTK lemmatizer in this list comprehension, specifically whether it is taking account of the POS tags?

```
clean_article_string = (article_db.loc[0,'clean_text']) # pandas dataframe cell containing string.
tokens = word_tokenize(clean_article_string)
treebank_tagged_tokens = tagger.tag(tokens)
wordnet_tagged_tokens = [(w,get_wordnet_pos(t)) for (w, t) in treebank_tagged_tokens]
lemmatized_tokens = [(lemmatizer.lemmatize(w).lower(),t) for (w,t) in wordnet_tagged_tokens]
print(len(set(wordnet_tagged_tokens)),(len(set(lemmatized_tokens))))
423 384
```

I'm using a converter I found on Stackoverflow to switch from treebank to Wordnet tokens, and it works fine. My issue is whether for `lemmatized_tokens` the lemmatizer is actually taking both the word and the tag of my `(w,t)` tuple into account, or if it is just looking at the `w` and lemmatizing based on that (presuming everything to be a noun). I tried...

```
lemmatized_tokens = [(lemmatizer.lemmatize(w,t)) for (w,t) in wordnet_tagged_tokens]
```

and

```
lemmatized_tokens = [(lemmatizer.lemmatize(w, pos=t)) for (w,t) in wordnet_tagged_tokens]
```

which produces a `KeyError: ''` in the Wordnet lemmatize function. So the initial code actually functions, but I don't know if it is using the POS tag or not. Does anyone know whether the lemmmatizer will be taking it into account in the working code, and/or if I can verify it is?

Comment: if you use `lemmatizer.lemmatize(w)`, then it will use the default POS tag `n`, the error suggests that some of the tags are empty - in this case, perhaps one could use a fallback to nouns, i.e., to use `lemmatizer.lemmatize(w, pos=t if t else 'n')`

Comment: Spot on. Yes some tags were empty because of the Wordnet conversion. Your suggested code worked and the total vocab reduced significantly now its accounting for the tags. Wonderful.

Comment: If you want to resubmit as an answer I'll confirm it correct.

Comment: Try this: https://gist.github.com/alvations/07758d02412d928414bb from https://github.com/alvations/pywsd (Disclaimer: shameless plug)

Comment: Looks interesting. So it lemmatizes and then automatically stems if lemmatizing fails? And I feed it pre-tagged tokens because it tags using the perceptron tagger? Is that right? - I have about 3 days experience with POS and lemmatizing so please forgive me for asking the obvious.

Comment: Yes, you're correct =) But you can add one more step, to check if stems get you a wordnet synset by using `neverstem=False`. And if all else fails, it returns the original string without lemmatization =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer by ewcz in comments. Labelled as community wiki. This helped me, might help others.

---

You use `lemmatizer.lemmatize(w)`, then it will use the default POS tag n, the error suggests that some of the tags are empty - in this case, perhaps one could use a fallback to nouns, i.e., to use 
`lemmatizer.lemmatize(w, pos=t if t else 'n')`